# Highest value to fill circle within Apex Charts

Tags: apexcharts

ApexChart Image Example:

[image: 1]

Ideally, the highest value (for this example, 7) would fill the circle.

Can anyone help change the default value of 100 become the highest value?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var options = {
          series: [3, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0],
          chart: {
          height: 550,
          type: 'radialBar',
        },
        plotOptions: {
          radialBar: {
            offsetY: 0,
            startAngle: 0,
            endAngle: 270,
            hollow: {
              margin: 0,
              size: '10%',
              background: 'transparent',
              image: undefined,
            },
            dataLabels: {
              enabled: true,
      
              value: {
                show: true,
              }
            }
          }
        },
        labels: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11'],
        legend: {
          show: true,
          floating: true,
          fontSize: '12px',
          position: 'left',
          offsetX: 190,
          offsetY: 7,
          labels: {
            useSeriesColors: true,
          },
          markers: {
            size: 0
          },
          formatter: function(seriesName, opts) {
            return seriesName + ":  " + opts.w.globals.series[opts.seriesIndex]
          },
          itemMargin: {
            vertical: 0
          }
        },
        responsive: [{
          breakpoint: 480,
          options: {
            legend: {
                show: false
            }
          }
        }]
        };

        var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart3"), options);
        chart.render();
    </script>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Using the Apex Charts docs for reference.

Comment: Looking at the source code for radialBar, it appears that the maximum of 100 is hard-coded; the [docs](https://apexcharts.com/docs/chart-types/radialbar-gauge/) also state in the first paragraph "... a circular numeric scale in terms of percentage". I think then that the best solution is to manipulate the data and set the `formatter` for the `dataLabels` and `legend` to translate back to the real values; see for instance [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m67cxhup/)